# Base URL is HTTPS But, All the Canonicals are HTTP how to Fix this

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I've modified my base URL and moved to HTTPs from HTTP but, My website canonicals are still HTTP. So, tell me how I can resolve this issue so, that the I can stop the 2-page indexing in Google search results.

Comment: do you have any SEO extensions installed? just change base url, reindex and flush magento cache....

Comment: Did you change *both* the secure and unsecure URL?